# Uncaught (in promise): QuotaExceededError Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, local-storage, angular5, quota, ionic-storage

**Already StackOverflow have this type question but none of the answers is helpful for me,**
**Here is my problem details**-
Getting error when I build the app in android device, its work fine in emulator and browser, but when I run the app into the device I get this error and my data could not save in storage.

```
vendor.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): QuotaExceededError
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:1)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:1)
```

Here is my dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
"@angular/common": "5.2.10",
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
"@angular/core": "5.2.10",
"@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
"@angular/http": "5.2.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.7.0",
"@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.7.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
"@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
"@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
"@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
"cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
"cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.3.2",
"emulator": "0.1.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionic-cache": "^3.0.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.5.10",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"
}
```

here is my app.module.ts imports array

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
LoginPageModule,
SignupPageModule,
DashboardPageModule,
TabPageModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  tabsPlacement: 'bottom',
  platforms: {
    ios: {
      tabsPlacement: 'bottom'
    }
  }
}),
CacheModule.forRoot(),
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
  name: '__mydb',
  driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']
}),
HttpClientModule,
],
```

I want to save data when a user loggedin success, here is my code of user login and save user to the storage.

```
this.authService.userLogin(this.user)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(typeof response.status);
        if (response.status === "ok") {
          spinner.dismiss();
          console.log(response.status);
          this.storage.ready().then(() => {
            this.storage.set('user',response);
          });

          this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
        } else {
          spinner.dismiss();
          console.log(response.status);
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: response.status,
            subTitle: response.msg,
            buttons: ['Dismiss']
          });
          alert.present()
        }
      })
```

Right direction would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some solution, Here I mention one of them:

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
  name: ‘__mydb’,
  driverOrder: [‘sqlite’, ‘websql’, ‘indexeddb’]
})
```

But it does not work for me.

After that
I just solve it using [ionic native storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/).

It works fine in android and ios.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try adding this line in the `app.module.ts`:

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
  name: ‘__mydb’,
  driverOrder: [‘sqlite’, ‘websql’, ‘indexeddb’]
})
```

Comment: Fixed the issue  by downloading Sqlite cordova plugin (find it in ionic native doc)

Comment: I already use the SQLite Cordova plugin, but could not work, I solve this problem using ionic-native-storage plugin